# How Do I extend Android Material Dark Theme

Tags: android, material-design

I know I might be making more than enough mistakes here. But do lemme know.
I've tried going through MaterialIO documentation the best way I can, and it all looks so spun up and complicated with a dozen links in each page redirecting me to another minor component.
That's when I decided to TRY it.

- I added materialIO stuff to my dependencies
- I then added Material to my manifest file, and wrote this

```
<application ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight" >
</application>
```

- Next, I made a `values/themes.xml` and `values-night/themes.xml` as instructed by some part of the material IO page.
- My intuition was to write a style tag in those resources that extended the Material theme and set my color values. The colors I found from the materialIO page :

  - Background (0dp elevation surface overlay)-->
  - Surface (with 1dp elevation surface overlay)-->
  - Primary
  - Secondary
  - On background
  - On Surface
  - On Primary
  - On Secondary
- So I started adding the tags to values-night/themes.xml. I couldn't apply `android:` to some tags and some tags raised errors when I did.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <style name="AppCompat.." parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
                <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/JDBG</item>
                <item name="colorSurface">@color/JDSurface</item>
                <item name="colorPrimary">@color/JDPrimary</item>
                <item name="android:colorSecondary">@color/JDSecondary</item>
                <item name="android:OnBackground">@color/JDOnBackground</item>
                <item name="android:OnSurface">@color/JDOnSurface</item>
                <item name="OnPrimary">@color/JDOnPrimary</item>
                <item name="OnSecondary">@color/JDOnSecondary</item>
        </style>
</resources>
```

- Then I added the colors to the respective `colors.xml` and `colors-night.xml` files, which told me that those values didn't have a declaration in the base values folder and it might raise issues.

I do not want to toil at nothing with very abstract documentation that leads me on ten directions at every point. Hence the question . . .
**Is there anything wrong I've done ?
What do I do next ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define your theme in a resources file.
For example `res/values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/....</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/....</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/....</item>
    .....
</style>
```

Define the colors in `res/values/colors.xml` and `res/values-night/colors.xml`.

Then apply the theme in the Manifest:

```
<application ...
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

Check also the [official guide.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes)

Comment: What if I need to switch day and night color themes, in-app?

Comment: @Jitin You can find info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme)